# How to continuously send feedback via AJAX responses to my client?

Tags: ajax

I have a mechanism that's triggered via AJAX and now have decided to optimize it by batching each main call into an AJAX call to avoid timeout issues (so the script doesn't run the 5 main processes I have in a shot). That's great and all and it works, but -

I want to send constant feedback to my browser when each step is done, unfortunately `wp_send_json` also calls `wp_die`, as it should, but this is not desirable  because it means that after it's done with the first step, it'll kill WP and restart and so, all my other messages won't be sent. What are my options to build a pipe-like system where I can constantly push updates to the browser in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_send_json`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/) just does a basic data sanitization under the hood using [`wp_json_encode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/) function.

So you can use PHP's built-in functionality `json_encode` the problem that you're going to have is keeping the connection alive, If you're not going to have a lot of visitors you can block the PHP thread by simply running a while true loop and echo data whenever it's ready.

```
while(true) {
    // BTW, You'll have to handle your data within the loop or in an outer process
    if($data_available) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        if($last_item) {
            wp_die();
        }
    }
}
```

You have to make sure you're sending `Keep-Alive` header and are tuning your script to provide sufficient requirements for this protocol feature.

Writing this code inside the WordPress's core is a little bit hard and might get confusing in the future, there is an alternative solution to this problem.

It's better to use a duplex protocol (like WebSocket) for this kind of data (which are getting ready over the time).
In PHP there is a very good library to write reactive code called [`ReactPHP`](https://reactphp.org/), You can simply integrate it with another library called [`React Socket`](https://reactphp.org/socket/) or [`Ratchet`](http://socketo.me/) (I can't remember correctly if ratchet does handle all stuff by it self or not).

Comment: I second WebSockets. My brief brush with marrying WordPress and HTTP long polling ended in bruises and tears.